# How to create a search engine for my list with reports

Tags: javascript, powerbi-desktop

I have some PowerBI and SSRS and I want to create a website with a search field. The search field should scan the reports descriptions and provide the demanding reports.

Question: What is the best way to create this search field? I did not find any usefull tutorials on youtube to do it.

[image: Should look like this]